# Integrating JSF, SPRING and Hibernate and always getting the error-org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf

I'm new to Spring. Trying to build a Web project using JSF Spring and hibernate in Maven but seems my application is not able to get the spring configuration XML.

Below is the **Stack Trace**:

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [co.MyJavaCode.spring.service.impl.UserDetailsServiceImpl] for bean with name 'userDetailsService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: co.MyJavaCode.spring.service.impl.UserDetailsServiceImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:622)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:591)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1397)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:968)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:735)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4745)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: co.MyJavaCode.spring.service.impl.UserDetailsServiceImpl
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1291)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:249)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:395)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1320)
    ... 19 more

Nov 09, 2018 5:00:26 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [co.MyJavaCode.spring.service.impl.UserDetailsServiceImpl] for bean with name 'userDetailsService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: co.MyJavaCode.spring.service.impl.UserDetailsServiceImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:622)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:591)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1397)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:968)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:735)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4745)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: co.MyJavaCode.spring.service.impl.UserDetailsServiceImpl
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1291)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:249)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:395)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1320)
    ... 19 more

Nov 09, 2018 5:00:26 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [co.MyJavaCode.spring.service.impl.UserDetailsServiceImpl] for bean with name 'userDetailsService' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: co.MyJavaCode.spring.service.impl.UserDetailsServiceImpl
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:622)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:591)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1397)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:968)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:735)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4745)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: co.MyJavaCode.spring.service.impl.UserDetailsServiceImpl
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1291)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:249)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:395)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1320)
    ... 19 more

Nov 09, 2018 5:00:26 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.2.10 ( 20150205-0906 https://svn.java.net/svn/mojarra~svn/tags/2.2.10@14334) for context '/JSF_SPRING_HIBERNATE'
Nov 09, 2018 5:00:27 PM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFO: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
Nov 09, 2018 5:00:27 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener$WebConfigResourceMonitor$Monitor <init>
INFO: Monitoring file:/C:/Users/x4180/workspace1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/JSF_SPRING_HIBERNATE/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
Nov 09, 2018 5:00:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
Nov 09, 2018 5:00:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/JSF_SPRING_HIBERNATE] startup failed due to previous errors
Nov 09, 2018 5:00:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Nov 09, 2018 5:00:27 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesJdbc
WARNING: The web application [JSF_SPRING_HIBERNATE] registered the JDBC driver [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
Nov 09, 2018 5:00:27 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase clearReferencesThreads
WARNING: The web application [JSF_SPRING_HIBERNATE] appears to have started a thread named [Mojarra-WebResourceMonitor-1-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 sun.misc.Unsafe.compareAndSwapInt(Native Method)
 java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger.compareAndSet(AtomicInteger.java:133)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.compareAndDecrementWorkerCount(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:421)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.decrementWorkerCount(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:430)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1048)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Nov 09, 2018 5:00:27 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks
SEVERE: The web application [JSF_SPRING_HIBERNATE] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.ActivityCorrelator$1] (value [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.ActivityCorrelator$1@66507bd3]) and a value of type [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.ActivityId] (value [ce07abca-cce2-4b61-8d6a-65a51418366a-17]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.
Nov 09, 2018 5:00:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Nov 09, 2018 5:00:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Nov 09, 2018 5:00:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 27085 ms
```

**POM.XML**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>JSF_SPRING_HIBERNATE</groupId>
    <artifactId>JSF_SPRING_HIBERNATE</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>JSF_SPRING_HIBERNATE Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>


    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring.version>4.1.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <jsf2.version>2.2.10</jsf2.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.8.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring ORM support -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSF Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsf2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${jsf2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- hibernate 4 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- database pool -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- sql server java connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.jre8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>JSF_SPRING_HIBERNATE</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**WEB.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**ApplicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
 xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.1.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.1.xsd">

 <!-- support spring annotation -->
 <context:annotation-config />
 <!-- support annotation transaction -->
 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

 <!-- declare datasource -->
 <bean id="dataSource"
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://CIS-GIASDBT2:3433;databaseName=PNXProjectBWrk;integratedSecurity=true" />
  <property name="username" value="root" />
  <property name="password" value="" />
 </bean>

 <!--Hibernate session factory configuration -->
 <bean id="sessionFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <!-- load hibernate configuration file -->
  <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
  <!-- where to find the ORM classes -->
  <property name="packagesToScan" value="co.MyJavaCode.hibernate.model" />
 </bean>

 <!-- Transaction manager -->
 <bean id="transactionManager"
  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
  <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
 </bean>

 <!-- service -->
 <bean id="userDetailsService" class="co.MyJavaCode.spring.service.impl.UserDetailsServiceImpl" />

 <!-- dao -->
 <bean id="userDetailsDao" class="co.MyJavaCode.spring.dao.impl.UserDetailsDaoImpl" />

</beans>
```

**faces-config.xml**

```
**<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
              http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">
    <application>
        <el-resolver>
            org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
        </el-resolver>
    </application>
</faces-config>**
```

Click link :[Package Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxIBj.jpg)
I'm stuck in the process and couldn't get what exactly I'm missing.  Tried to do it in several way but didn't succeed. googled a lot but couldn't get the solution.

Please help!

UserDetailsServiceImpl.Java

```
package co.MyJavaCode.spring.service.impl;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import co.MyJavaCode.hibernate.model.UserDetails;
import co.MyJavaCode.spring.dao.UserDetailsDao;
import co.MyJavaCode.spring.service.UserDetailsService;

@Component
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsDao userDetailsDao;

    @Override
    public UserDetails getuserDetails(int id) {
        return userDetailsDao.getuserDetails(id);
    }

    @Override
    public List<UserDetails> getAllUserDetails() {
        return userDetailsDao.getAllUserDetails();
    }

    public UserDetailsDao getUserDetailsDao() {
        return userDetailsDao;
    }

}
```

UserDetailsDaoImpl.java

```
package co.MyJavaCode.spring.dao.impl;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import co.MyJavaCode.hibernate.model.UserDetails;
import co.MyJavaCode.spring.dao.UserDetailsDao;

@Component
public class UserDetailsDaoImpl implements UserDetailsDao {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public UserDetails getuserDetails(int id) {
        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(UserDetails.class, id);
        return userDetails;
    }

    @Transactional
    @Override
    public List<UserDetails> getAllUserDetails() {

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<UserDetails> userDetails = (List<UserDetails>) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createCriteria(UserDetails.class).list();

        //or below query

        /*
         * @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") List<UserDetails> userDetails =
         * (List<UserDetails>)sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(
         * "from UserDetails").list();
         */        
        return userDetails;
    }

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show me your package structure? Normally, this is a problem with the component scan.

Comment: Added the package structure

Comment: You added the `@Component` or `@Service annotation` to your classes, right?

Comment: I've added @Component in my UserDetailsServiceImpl.java and UserDetailsDaoImpl.java. Attached the code snippebts for both these classes.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion on this?

Comment: I hope my answer solves your problem, or at least guide you to your solution. :)

Comment: If you don’t mind marking my answer as correct it would be awesome! Also upvoting!

Comment: Done ✅ Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem has to do with the component scan. In this [blog](https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-integration-example/), it seems that in order to use your configuration, you must add the following annotation, `@ManagedBean` to your beans.

Still, there is an easier way to do a complete scan, which is allowing Spring to do it for you. For this you might try deleting the following lines from your *applicationContext.xml*.

```
<!-- service -->
<bean id="userDetailsService" class="co.MyJavaCode.spring.service.impl.UserDetailsServiceImpl" />

<!-- dao -->
<bean id="userDetailsDao" class="co.MyJavaCode.spring.dao.impl.UserDetailsDaoImpl" />
```

After deleting those lines, add the following line to the same file.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="co.MyJavaCode"/>
```

This will automatically scan all your files that have either the `@Component` or `@Service` annotation. I Added `co.MyJavaCode` as the base package, because it looks like every class is inside that package, but if not, just create a base package and add everything to it and use it as reference for your auto-scan. Hope it helps!

Comment: New versions of spring also understand the cdi `@Named` annotation.